# Storing IP votes: SQL vs. NoSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, list, ip, nosql

I want to keep track of the item ids that someone from a certain IP voted on. So a schema along the lines of:

IP   |  Votes

---

IP1 | 563, 342, 343, 654, 12 (These are the item ids)

IP2 | 1, 235, 1245, 895, 326

This would obviously violate atomicity on the votes column, and most people are going to suggest normalising it and using foreign keys.

But my issue is that I want to keep only 1 record per IP. I think it would improve performance since scalability is an issue and the number of rows would become catastrophic after a certain period. Going through the entire table just to find all the IP1s or IP2s would be a nightmare.

I am a total newbie at designing schema, so would something like NoSQL be better suited for this type of thing, since that list would be ever growing? Or is there a RDBMS solution to this?

Comment: Clearly you are a total newbie if you don't want to take advantage of the tried-and-true wisdom of creating a proper `IPVotes` table with one row per IP and per vote.

Comment: Totally :). If you have some literature to read up upon for similar situations to this, feel free to share it. I'm sure it'd help a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Most people", of which I am one, are correct. A schema like you suggest where having a single row per IP at the expense of relational integrity and consistency is not going to perform notably better, and will, in fact, cause you considerable trouble in fairly short order. Don't do it. Relational databases can handle more than you think, especially with proper indexing.

Whether you should use NoSQL is a separate question. A document database (for example) would be appropriate if you are primarily concerned with the votes of an individual IP address, can keep voting records self-contained with whatever is being voted on to avoid joining external documents, and are less concerned with slicing and dicing aggregates. I don't know what you're designing, but I suspect a relational approach is likely well enough suited to it.

Comment: With thousands of voters, and dozens of votes per voter, if not more, I think there'd be performance issues, even with proper indexing. I am more and more leaning towards a document dabatase like you mentioned.

Comment: For a table as simple as user_id/item_id/vote, I would expect to get well into the millions of rows without breaking a sweat.

Comment: Would there an advantage memory wise to using the NoSQL approach?

Comment: "I think there'd be performance issues..." Stop *thinking*, you have a hypothesis, and start *testing*. Create an example schema and ram it full of data. Take whatever you think you'll have at production scale, multiply by ten, and go for it, jam in tons of synethic test data. Find out when the thing crumbles.